# In SQL, is it possible to use a dummy column in an insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have some insertion:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, dummy, col3) values (1,1,1,1), (2,2,2,2)
```

The "dummy" column doesn't really exist, it's needed because I generate the insert statement, even the column header, and some columns need to be ignored based on situation, but the data are still the same, it would make my life a lot easier if I don't need to mess with the data and just the header.

So I guess to put it another way:  Is it possible to "ignore" a column on insert statement.

---

To put it in another another way, I am trying to do a insert statement on 3 columns with 4 columns worth of data, and is wondering if there is any way to deal with this at the SQL level instead of at the code logic level.

---

So here is a longer example, I have this 2D array.

```
{ {101,102,103,104}, {201,202,203,204}, ... }
```

I have a table with the following columns

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Now one user says:

```
"I would like to only use col1, col2, col4"
```

And another user says:

```
"I would like to only use col2, col3"
```

How do I do this if I do not want to mess with the 2D data array?

```
insert into table (col1, col2, ignore, col4) 
    values (101,102,103,104), (201,202,203,204)


insert into table (ignore, col2, col3, ignore) 
    values (101,102,103,104), (201,202,203,204)
```

Notice that the order matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a preety crazy requirement but there is a way to make it work.

With a table `t` which has 3 columns `(a,b,c)`, you can use the tables value constructor, available in SQL-Server 2008 and above. Note how you can change which columns of the input will be inserted into the table by altering only one line of the SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO t 
  (a, b, c) 
SELECT 
  col1, col3, col4            -- this is the only line needs configured
                              -- col2 is ignored
FROM 
  ( VALUES
    ( 1, 2, 3, 4), 
    (11,12,13,14),
    (21,22,23,24),
    (31,21,33,34)
   ) AS x 
     (col1, col2, col3, col4)
;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68404/5)**

If the table has 4 columns `(a,b,c,d)` - as many as the value list - a similar approach would be:

```
INSERT INTO t 
  (a, b, c, d) 
SELECT 
  col1, NULL, col3, col4         -- this is the only line needs configured
                                 -- col2 is ignored and NULLs are put
                                 -- into column "b"
FROM         --- rest of the code is the same
```

Comment: From the latest update by the OP, it seems that there actually are many columns in the table but different users want to use different ones (like just 1, 2 and 4; or just 2 and 3). In the end, it seems like the problem is laziness: instead of excluding columns twice (from the column list and from the value list) when building an INSERT statement, the OP wants to exclude them just once (from the column list, but in a way that the value list remains valid).

Comment: Brilliant!  I already gaved up and just ended up messing with both the header and data.  But your solution is quite awesome.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu: Which one?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to "ignore" a column on insert statement.

Yes, don't include it in the fields list. For example:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
```

will only insert values into `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and will leave the remainder of the columns (in the new row) with their default values.

Comment: But the data would be not aligned correctly.  The data would still be (1,1,1,1), (2,2,2,2)

Comment: @YongkeBillYu: I'll be honest, I'm really not sure what you mean. Don't include the values in the value list?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to do a insert statement on 3 column with 4 column worth of data, and is wondering if there is any way to deal with this at the SQL level instead of at the code logic level.

Comment: And I must keep the order the same.  And any column (not just the last one) can be ignored.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, please edit your question and really explain what's happening; there is clearly **a lot of context missing** for me to really help you.

Comment: Ok, added longer example.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, okay what you're wanting to do isn't possible; you are going to have to modify the array of values for sure.